# jQuery UI Tabs - SlideToggle?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The following code rotates through tabs that I've set and does a nice job of fading in and out, however, I was wondering if it could be tweaked to have the content slide in and out.

```
$("#product_rotator").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 7000);
```

I tried changing "toggle" to "slideToggle" but that didn't work...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Vindoh, I also tried the following solution and it worked

```
$("#product_rotator").tabs({fx:{width: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 7000);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the following `fx` option.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
  collapsible: true,
  fx: {
    height: 'show', opacity: 'show'
    }
});
```